# MapBox, can it use the z-coordinate in a GeoJSON file to make lines "hover" over the ground?

Tags: mapbox, geojson

In MapBox, is there a way to use the z coordinate to make lines in a GeoJSON file "hover" above ground?

I have a GeoJSON file with lines with x, y and z coordinates. The x and y coordinates are in EPSG: 4326. The definition of GeoJSON allows the z coordinate to be meters.

The GeoJSON is something like this:

```
<
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "centros_lat",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "Id": "center01"},
        "geometry": { "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [ [ -3.235834, 38.832989, 32 ], [ -3.234574, 38.834453, 32 ], ...]
        }
    }, ....
]
}
```

> 

Using this GeoJSON as a source in MapBox works just fine, but it just displays the line on the terrain level and does not seem to be using the z coordinate at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS does not support LineString features raised above the ground.

There is a kind of workaround if you convert the LineString to a Polygon (with some kind of thickness), then display it using a `fill-extrusion` type, using `fill-extrusion-height` and `fill-extrusion-base` to set the elevation.